# Bash - While read line from file print first and second column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, do-while

I have a test file like below. (but the actual file has 1000+ lines and many columns)

```
apple,2
mango,5
coconut,10
```

I want to print this file as below.

```
I have apple and the count is 2
I have mango and the count is 5
I have coconut and the count is 10
```

I tried `while read line` with `awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`, but im not getting the actual output. 
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: And what do you get instead? / Post the full code, not just some snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, '{print "I have", $1, "and the count is", $2}' file
```

```
I have apple and the count is 2
I have mango and the count is 5
I have coconut and the count is 10
```

Though `awk` is recommended but if you are looking for a bash loop then use:

```
while IFS=, read -r f c; do
    echo "I have $f and the count is $c"
done < file
```

Comment: If I want to add single quote `'` like `'apple' ` how can I edit this?

Comment: Using `awk` you can do: `awk -F, '{print "I have \047" $1 "\047 and the count is", $2}' file` OR using `bash` use: `while IFS=, read -r f c; do  echo "I have '$f' and the count is $c"; done < file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in sed. Replace the beginning of each line and the comma with related strings:

```
$ sed 's/^/I have /;s/,/ and the count is /' file
I have apple and the count is 2
I have mango and the count is 5
I have coconut and the count is 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small file, you can use `read` to split the line.

```
while IFS=, read fruit count; do
  echo "I have $fruit and the count is $count"
done < file.txt
```

For larger files, it is inefficient to iterate using `bash`, and something like `awk` to read the entire file would be more appropriate.